# Need help optimising PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I am assuming I would need to JOIN the two queries before the for loop but what would be the best to optimise the following code:

```
$LocationArray0 = array();
$LocationArray1 = array();
$LocationArray2 = array();
$LocationArray3 = array();
$LocationArray4 = array();

foreach($Bodyshops as $Bodyshop) {
    $Query = "SELECT BodyshopID, BodyshopName, BodyshopLongitude, BodyshopLatitude FROM FusionBodyshops WHERE BodyshopID = '$Bodyshop'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $Query); 
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ( $rows != 0 ) {
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i ++ ) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
            $BodyshopID = $row['BodyshopID'];
            $BodyshopName = $row['BodyshopName'];
            $BodyshopLatitude = $row['BodyshopLatitude'];
            $BodyshopLongitude = $row['BodyshopLongitude'];
            $query2 = "SELECT Tier FROM FusionBodyshopSettings WHERE BodyshopID = '$Bodyshop' AND BusinessID = '$UserCompany'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2); 
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
            if ( $row2['Tier'] == "0") {
                array_push($LocationArray0, "'" . str_replace("'", "",$BodyshopName) . "', '" . $BodyshopLatitude . "', '" . $BodyshopLongitude . "'"); //$row['BodyshopID'] . ", " .
            }elseif ( $row2['Tier'] == "1") {
                array_push($LocationArray1, "'" . str_replace("'", "",$BodyshopName) . "', '" . $BodyshopLatitude . "', '" . $BodyshopLongitude . "'"); //$row['BodyshopID'] . ", " .
            }elseif ( $row2['Tier'] == "2") {
                array_push($LocationArray2, "'" . str_replace("'", "",$BodyshopName) . "', '" . $BodyshopLatitude . "', '" . $BodyshopLongitude . "'"); //$row['BodyshopID'] . ", " .
            }elseif ( $row2['Tier'] == "3") {
                array_push($LocationArray3, "'" . str_replace("'", "",$BodyshopName) . "', '" . $BodyshopLatitude . "', '" . $BodyshopLongitude . "'"); //$row['BodyshopID'] . ", " .
            }elseif ( $row2['Tier'] == "4") {
                array_push($LocationArray4, "'" . str_replace("'", "",$BodyshopName) . "', '" . $BodyshopLatitude . "', '" . $BodyshopLongitude . "'"); //$row['BodyshopID'] . ", " .
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Never execute a query inside a loop. 2. See JOINs

Comment: why you use your query inside the loop? If you need to run the query for one time, then just use it outside the loop, if not then use `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited for the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace ALL of your code with something like this:

```
SELECT a.BodyshopID
     , a.BodyshopName
     , a.BodyshopLongitude
     , a.BodyshopLatitude 
     , b.Tier
  FROM FusionBodyshops a
  JOIN FusionBodyshopSettings b
    ON b.BodyshopID = a.BodyshopID 
 WHERE a.BodyshopID IN ($Bodyshops) -- a list of bodyshops
   AND b.BusinessID = $UserCompany;
```

Now see prepared statements.